# Excel: Nest IF condition inside COUNTIF?

Tags: excel, logic, formula

I have a few dropdowns to determine what should be used as conditions for data calculations, these are:

- Country OR Supervisor (dropdown changes depending on two radio buttons, and content is cleared when selection is made)
- Month
- Channel

So instead of writing a long and complicated formula like this (where I would replace the text string with the actual COUNTIFS formula corresponding to the text string):

```
=IFS(
         AND(radioCheck=1,ISBLANK(D3),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Country blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(D5),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Country Month blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,ISBLANK(D3),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),ISBLANK(D6)),"Country Channel blank",

         AND(radioCheck=1,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),ISBLANK(D5),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Month blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(D5),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Country Month blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(D6)),"Month Channel blank",

         AND(radioCheck=1,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),ISBLANK(D6)),"Channel blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,ISBLANK(D3),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),ISBLANK(D6)),"Country Channel blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(D6)),"Month Channel blank",

         AND(radioCheck=1,ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(D6)),"Country Month Channel blank",
         AND(radioCheck=1,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Country Month Channel Chosen",

         AND(radioCheck=2,ISBLANK(D3),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Supervisor blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(D5),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Supervisor Month blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,ISBLANK(D3),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),ISBLANK(D6)),"Supervisor Channel blank",

         AND(radioCheck=2,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),ISBLANK(D5),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Month blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(D5),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Supervisor Month blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(D6)),"Month Channel blank",

         AND(radioCheck=2,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),ISBLANK(D6)),"Channel blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,ISBLANK(D3),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),ISBLANK(D6)),"Supervisor Channel blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(D6)),"Month Channel blank",

         AND(radioCheck=2,ISBLANK(D3),ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(D6)),"Supervisor Month Channel blank",
         AND(radioCheck=2,NOT(ISBLANK(D3)),NOT(ISBLANK(D5)),NOT(ISBLANK(D6))),"Supervisor Month Channel Chosen"
)
```

*(radiocheck = 1 means country dropdown, and radiocheck 2 means supervisor dropdown. D3 = country OR supervisor dropdown, D5 is month dropdown and D6 is channel dropdown)*

..for every field of my data that I want to be calculated based on these three/four conditions, I want to be able to achieve something like this instead (in the example, month becomes blank, so - remove month as a condition):

I.e:

```
=COUNTIFS(rawNPS,">=9",
          IF($D$5="","",rawYYMMM,$D$5),
          rawAgent,K20,rawChannel,$D$6
)
```

..so that IF there is no choice made in the dropdown in D5, then rawYYMMM will NOT be a condition in the formula.

Is this somehow possible? I cannot provide much more examples than this,

Comment: Do it backwards. Instead IF inside COUNTIF, make COUNTIF inside IF. Something like IF (all blank choices then count like this Else count like this other way)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns that is what I am trying to avoid, as it requires a lot of IF's. I would have to check so many times with IFs and ANDs with nested ANDs. So far, just to check if one of the fields is blank or not, or if everyone is selected, I have EIGHT IF formulas.. three for each of the checkbox choices and two for the "none is blank" (one for each of the two checkbox choices). And those eight rules, only covers if ONE of the fields are blank.. not if two are, or three. So you see, it quickly builds up, and the formula field will eventually not take all of the code.

Comment: Can you provide a dataset - it sounds like an interessting question - but I have problems to get it.

Comment: @Ike hmm, not really. But I updated the question now to maybe better give you a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entries in `rawYYMMM` and `D5` are positive, non-zero numerics:

`=COUNTIFS(rawNPS,">=9",rawYYMMM,IF($D$5="",">0",$D$5),rawAgent,K20,rawChannel,$D$6)`

If the entries in `rawYYMMM` and `D5` are numerics which may be positive, negative or zero:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(rawNPS,">=9",rawYYMMM,IF($D$5="",{">0","<=0"},$D$5),rawAgent,K20,rawChannel,$D$6))`

If the entries in `rawYYMMM` and `D5` are text:

`=COUNTIFS(rawNPS,">=9",rawYYMMM,IF($D$5="","*",$D$5),rawAgent,K20,rawChannel,$D$6)`

Comment: Wow, yes, this makes so much sense. Keep the Criteria Range and just enter an IF statement in the Criteria itself. Thank you :D